# Get Data From .docx file like one big String in C#

Tags: c#, .net, office-interop, docx

I want to read data - like string, from .docx file from C# code. I look through some of the issues but didn't understand which one to use.

I'm trying to use `ApplicationClass Application = new ApplicationClass();` but I get t

Error:

> The type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass' has no
>   constructors defined

And I want to get full text from my docx file, NOT SEPARATED WORDS !

```
foreach (FileInfo f in docFiles)
{
    Application wo = new Application();
    object nullobj = Missing.Value;
    object file = f.FullName;
    Document doc = wo.Documents.Open(ref file, .... . . ref nullobj);
    doc.Activate();
    doc. == ??    
}
```

I want to know how can I get whole text from docx file?

Comment: I hope this will helps you https://forums.asp.net/p/1688845/4463018.aspx/1?Re+Read+doc+or+docx+file+with+formatting

Comment: [This constructor supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.applicationclass.applicationclass(v=office.11))

Comment: `docx` is actually `Zip`. You can unzip using `sharpziplib` and read `word\document.xml` or get picture using media directory.

Comment: In fact it is more than a zip, it is an OPC package. If you want to start manually reading the files inside the archive, use System.Packaging

Comment: I have console application, I'm using it like a service. So I cant use asp solutions

Comment: If you're running unattended on a server, you shouldn't use the Office Automation libraries. They do not play well with headless servers, may occasionally pop up dialogs, and so forth. For post 2007 formats, your best bet is using the System.Packaging namespace, as @AndersForsgren said.

Comment: I think ZipPackage is the most suitable solution for me,now I'm trying  to extract text, but I can't do yet. I hope I'll do.Thanks for advice.

Comment: and how can I get whole text from my docx file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This Is what I want to extract whole text from docx file !

```
    using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(filename))
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    zip.Extract(@"word/document.xml", stream);
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); 
    XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmldoc.Load(stream);
    string PlainTextContent = xmldoc.DocumentElement.InnerText;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try

```
Word.Application interface instead of ApplicationClass.
```

[Understanding Office Primary Interop Assembly Classes and Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247302%28office.11%29.aspx)

Comment: I said ApplicationClass wordApp = new ApplicationClass(); gets me error

Comment: Because you can't do that. You should use Application, instead, as geek told you. I.e. `Word.Application = new Word.Application();`

Comment: `Application wo = new Application();
  object nullobj = Missing.Value;
  object file = f.FullName;
  Document doc = wo.Documents.Open(ref file, .... . . ref nullobj);
  doc.Activate();
  doc.` => I want to knwo how can I get whole text from docx file ?`

Comment: check out these links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296743/how-can-i-query-a-word-docx-in-an-asp-net-app  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492738/how-to-extract-plain-text-from-a-docx-file-using-the-new-ooxml-support-in-apache

Comment: In which library can I find XWPFWordExtractor ?

Comment: But I think that link are not for c#

Answer (score 0):

The .docx format as the other Microsoft Office files that end with "x" is simply a ZIP package that you can open/modify/compress.

So use an Office Open XML library like [this](http://simpleooxml.codeplex.com).

Answer (score 0):

Enjoy.

Make sure you are using .Net Framework 4.5.

```
using NUnit.Framework;
    [TestFixture]
    public class GetDocxInnerTextTestFixture
    {
        private string _inputFilepath = @"../../TestFixtures/TestFiles/input.docx";

        [Test]
        public void GetDocxInnerText()
        {
            string documentText = DocxInnerTextReader.GetDocxInnerText(_inputFilepath);

            Assert.IsNotNull(documentText);
            Assert.IsTrue(documentText.Length > 0);
        }
    }

using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Xml;
    public static class DocxInnerTextReader
    {
        public static string GetDocxInnerText(string docxFilepath)
        {
            string folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(docxFilepath);
            string extractionFolder = folder + "\\extraction";

            if (Directory.Exists(extractionFolder))
                Directory.Delete(extractionFolder, true);

            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(docxFilepath, extractionFolder);
            string xmlFilepath = extractionFolder + "\\word\\document.xml";

            var xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmldoc.Load(xmlFilepath);

            return xmldoc.DocumentElement.InnerText;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add some references from assemblies such as:

```
System.Xml
System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
```

Second you should be certain of calling these using in your class:

```
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Xml;
```

Then you can use below code:

```
public string DocxToString(string docxPath)
{
    // Destination of your extraction directory
    string extractDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(docxPath) + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(docxPath) + ".tmp";
    // Delete old extraction directory
    if (Directory.Exists(extractDir)) Directory.Delete(extractDir, true);
    // Extract all of media an xml document in your destination directory
    ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(docxPath, extractDir);

    XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
    // Load XML file contains all of your document text from the extracted XML file
    xmldoc.Load(extractDir + "\\word\\document.xml");
    // Delete extraction directory
    Directory.Delete(extractDir, true);
    // Read all text of your document from the XML
    return xmldoc.DocumentElement.InnerText;
}
```

Enjoy...